# Annotating x axis points using pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, annotations, labeling

How do I annotate both x,y points of my plotted graph using pyplot of matplotlib? I am working with python 2.7.12.

[pyplot image graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba183.png)

As of now I have got the labels for y axis points using the following code:

```
for i,j in zip(c1,c2):
    fig1.annotate('%s' %j, xy=(i,j), xytext=(1,0), textcoords='offset points')
```

Comment: What is your problem ? A simple way to use `annotate`'s paramater is `(<text_you_wish_to_draw>, <x, y coords as a tuple>)`. You seem to do this, even though you're naming `x, y` as `i, j` which is a bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: Code:        temp='('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')'
  #prints temp ie a string onto i,j co ordinates
  fig1.text(x,y,temp)